# TeXLive 2019/Linux: kpsewhich can't find symlinked paths under $HOME/texmf

Tags: texmf, kpsewhich

I am trying to figure out if I can switch from Mac back to Linux after a gap of 10+ years. I installed an Ubuntu derivative on the machine, and installed TeXLive 2019 (vanilla) using the equivs business to create a dummy package called texlive-local, so that I can trick the OS into thinking that TeX is installed. This is necessary because Ubuntu LTS tex packages are outdated.

My paths are fine. I can execute pdflatex, etc. perfectly fine, and documents containing standard latex classes (or rather anything under /usr/local/texlive/2019 ...) work fine.

The problem starts when I try to compile anything that needs my custom authored classes (I have several), which I installed under /home/user/texmf (see details below).

Actually, after I initially had problems, I copied (cp -R as user, not root, not sudo) the entire texmf-local tree from /usr/local/texlive to /home/user/texlive, and placed symbolic links to folders containing my custom class files under /home/user/texmf/tex/latex/local/. While copying the empty tree from /usr/local/texlive is not required, doing so ensures that I have the right TDS tree under ~/texmf. It is good practice to do so. So, I have the following symlinks (ln -s):

```
customclass ---> ../../../../../Somepath/customclass
classone ---> ../../../../../Somepath/classone
classtwo ---> ../../../../../Somepath/classtwo
```

under /home/user/texmf/tex/latex/local where the .cls and .sty files are located under the symlinked folders above. I am writing this explicitly here so that no one has any misunderstanding about the nature of my texmf tree - the symlinks are to folders containing the class files, and not to the class files themselves.

```
$kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
/home/user/texmf
```

I have tried setting TEXMFHOME explicitly at the end of my .bashrc, and also tried to manually export the variable, and added it to /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf.cnf.

I have been a LaTeX user for about 22 years, and I do NOT recall using LaTeX being this hard under Linux.

On Mac, this was simple - just placing symlinks under ~/Library/texmf took care of everything. IIRC that was also the case (~/texmf) in the old days when I used LaTeX on Linux. Apparently, not anymore.

I have searched for several answers on stackexchange, and elsewhere, tried out what I found there, but it does not work. Any file using custom classes, still fails, with kpsewhich failing to find the .cls files. I have run kpsewhich on command line - my custom classes yield blank input, while article.cls produces the path to article.cls.

Edit: Yes, I have run texhash ~/texmf, and sudo texhash multiple times.

What am I missing? Before someone suggests the obvious - explicitly copy the files over to texmf, I do not want to do that. My folders containing class files are sync'ed across several machines using a combination of rsync, and cron jobs, and I don't want to maintain two copies of the same file. A symbolic link is the right tool for the job.

Edit: I backup the folders containing my class files, not ~/Library/texmf (on Mac) and not ~/texmf (on Linux). I just symlink to the backed up folder on each OS. There are multiple machines that use these class files (I run a lab, and my grad students need to be all on the same page).

Is kpsewhich on the Linux version of TeXLive broken in the sense that it cannot handle symlinks?

Given that the various answers I have found on stack exchange have slightly different situations from mine (the equivs + TeXLive install mainly), this question is not a duplicate.

Edit: I figured it out, see my answer below. The problem is that kpsewhich is lazy, and does not want to look at symlinks unless a *real* directory is also located at that level.

Comment: Where in ~/texmf did you place the symlinks? Did you set up the proper TDS tree structure?

Comment: @cfr What do sensible backup habits, avoiding chaos, and redundant copies of the same files that may lead to inconsistency, have to do with the choice of the underlying OS?

Comment: @HerbSchulz I did mention that a) I copied the texmf-local directory tree over from /usr/local/texlive, and b) the symlinks are under tex/latex/local. If I am actually missing any details, let me know.

Comment: `texhash` is irrelevant for `~/texmf`. The directory is searched completely and not by database (unless you changed the default config).

Comment: @cfr You seem to be assuming things that are explicitly ruled out in the text of my question. Where have I mentioned that I want to use ~/Library/texmf as the tree under Linux? And, again, yes, I use symlinks because it is utterly senseless to have multiple copies of the same file scattered everywhere. And no, I don't backup ~/texmf or ~/Library/texmf. I only backup my own class files. Are you trying to imply that kpsewhich on Linux is incapable of handling symlinks?

Comment: @cfr I may not *need* to copy texmf-local but doing so is a sensible way of ensuring that I have the right directory structure. I think it should be encouraged as good practice.

Comment: @cfr That is why I am puzzled. The stuff is at the right place. The texmf tree has exactly the same structure as the template texmf-local under /usr/local/texlive. The TEXMFHOME variable under kpsewhich points to the right location. Do I conclude that kpsewhich under Linux is broken, and can't understand symlinks?

Comment: I'm not implying any of the things you say I'm implying. And kpsewhich has no trouble with symbolic links. But note that we have no idea where yours point. You don't need the `local` but it won't hurt anything.

Comment: Try `mkdir -p ~/texmf/tex/latex/class && touch ~/texmf/tex/latex/class/class.cls` and then `kpsewhich class.cls`. (`kpsewhich` won't care it isn't really a class.) If that works try `mv ~/texmf/tex/latex/class ~/` sym link `~/class` and retest. You need to eliminate stuff here to narrow it down because sym links work fine and there's no reason they won't (except on Windows or a file system which doesn't support them or whatever).

Comment: @cfr My symlinks point to different locations where I keep the relevant class files. They are functionally arranged to where they belong from a work standpoint. For instance, there is a letters folder under Research/Correspondence/Templates. Then there is a labmanuals folder under Research/Resources/Templates, etc. There are several (15 actually) such folders. All they share in common is that symlinks to these folders are located under ~/texmf/tex/latex/local. This is the only sensible way to arrange things in a heterogeneous computing situation where essential templates have to be shared.

Comment: I'd question whether it is the 'only sensible way'. I don't doubt it is 'a sensible way'. But ways are multitudinous and there is rarely only one way. For example, if you have your custom files in a version control repository, `~/texmf` may just be a working copy. (Or, of course, your 15 directories may each be working copies. Or both.) What I sync and backup is an svn database. The rest can be deleted and recreated at will. (This goes for TeX custom stuff and content and CTAN packages and ....) *Of course*, mine isn't the only sensible way. But it is one.

Answer (score 1):

@cfr You will not believe what just happened.

I liked your idea of creating a dummy class file under a dummy class folder under texmf.

So, I went ahead and did the following:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/texmf/tex/latex/local/class
$ cd ~/texmf/tex/latex/local/class
$ touch class.cls
```

Then I looked at kpsewhich output:

```
$ kpsewhich class.cls
/home/user/texmf/tex/latex/local/class/class.cls
```

So far so good. Then, I do not know why, I just had a hunch, call it a vague memory of how binary trees are searched, I tried, without doing anything else:

```
$kpsewhich letterwithfancieruniversityheader.cls
/home/user/texmf/tex/latex/local/letters/letterwithfancieruniversityheader.cls
```

!!!

Then for completeness,

```
$ rm ~/texmf/tex/latex/local/class/class.cls
```

And kpsewhich still finds my letter class file.

Apparently, texmf requires the presence of at least one *real* directory at the same level as symlinks. If it does not find it - my hunch is that kpsewhich is lazy and just looks at the size of the directory to decide if the next level traversal is empty, it quits looking.

This sounds like a bug in kpsewhich, or maybe it is an annoying feature. Either way, its a kpsewhich quirk to be aware of if you are sensibly using symlinks to point to templates you need, in a networked environment.

Comment: Report it? That seems very weird. I tested the sym links to double-check, but I never destroyed my working copy of `~/texmf`. Note that `local` is not standard. Standard would be `~/texmf/tex/latex/class/class.cls`.